# MySQL DATEDIFF with an Alias column

Tags: mysql, sql, date, subquery

I have a `DATE` column called `start_date`. I have created a new alias column for `end_date` - which is simply the `start_date` of the next record, minus one day.

Now I also want to create another alias column called `num_days` which will output the difference between the `start_date` and `end_date`. Here is my current query:

```
SELECT td1.*,
(
    SELECT DATE_SUB(td2.start_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    FROM test_date td2
    WHERE id = td1.id + 1
) AS end_date,

DATEDIFF(end_date, td1.start_date) AS num_days

FROM test_date td1
```

However I am getting an error: `Unknown column 'end_date' in 'field list'`. I understand this is because it can't reference an alias within the same `select` - so how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases defined in the `SELECT` clause cannot be reused in the same clause. You need to either repeat the expression, or use a derived table (cte or subquery).

The second option would look like:

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    DATEDIFF(end_date, td1.start_date) AS num_days
FROM (
    SELECT 
        td1.*,
        (
            SELECT td2.start_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY
            FROM test_date td2
            WHERE id = td1.id + 1
        ) AS end_date
    FROM test_date td1
) t
```

Alternatively, you can also join:

```
SELECT
    td1.*,
    td2.start_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY
    DATEDIFF(td2.start_date, td1.start_date) - 1 AS num_days
FROM test_date td1
LEFT JOIN test_date td2 ON td2.id = td1.id + 1
```

Side note: if you are running MySQL 8.0, you can simply use `LEAD()` to retrieve the date of the next record, which would be both simpler to write and more efficient.