# Use an alias in the datediff & Order By statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Why does the below code not work when I use the alias 'enddates' in the datediff (It throws up the error 'invalid column name: enddates')?

It works if I use the alias without the datediff (i.e. just ordering by enddates)

It also works if I copy the whole enddates formula into the datediff. But why can't I use the alias in the datediff? Thought the whole point of an alias is you can refer to it to shorten the code.

I did see something similar posted before, but there wasn't an answer

````
p.start_date,
(
  select min(p2.end_date) pend_date from projects p2 
  where p2.end_date not in
(select start_date from projects p3) and p2.end_date > p.start_date 
) enddates
from projects p 
where p.start_date not in 
(select end_date from projects) 
order by datediff(day, start_date,enddates), start_date```
````

Comment: hi, perhaps might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61559097/mysql-datediff-with-an-alias-column

Comment: Do you want to know why? (in which case you'll have to ask a microsoft engineer) or how to work with it?

Comment: @jspcal Thanks. Though the answer "Aliases defined in the SELECT clause cannot be reused in the same clause" is not correct as I can use enddates in the same clause (I can use it in the orderby part, without the datediff).

Comment: @DaleK I know a way around it is doing a subquery, as I mentioned. I want to know why. 
The point of a coding language is it is composed of logical rules that make it easier to learn- usually there's a logical reason you can/cannot do something and you don't need to ask the MS engineers why. 
If coding is full of lots of random irrational nuances, it would be 10 x more difficult to learn. 
I assume there's a more general rule behind this but as I said in the previous comment, the one given in the other thread is incorrect.